Decoding a mapping in Solidity: Type library IterableMapping is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct IterableMapping.Map storage pointer
Context
I am storing the content of the following mapping into a file:
pragma solidity >=0.8.25 <0.9.0;
import "test/TestConstants.sol";

library IterableMapping {
  // Iterable mapping from string[] to uint;
  struct Map {
    string[] keys;
    mapping(string => uint256) values;
    mapping(string => uint256) indexOf;
    mapping(string => bool) inserted;
  }

  function get(Map storage map, string memory key) public view returns (uint256) {
    return map.values[key];
  }

  function getKeys(Map storage map) public view returns (string[] memory) {
    return map.keys;
  }

  function getValues(Map storage map) public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
    uint256[] memory listOfValues = new uint256[](_MAX_NR_OF_TEST_LOG_VALUES_PER_LOG_FILE);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < map.keys.length - 1; i++) {
      listOfValues[i] = map.values[map.keys[i]];
    }
    return listOfValues;
  }

  function getKeyAtIndex(Map storage map, uint256 index) public view returns (string memory) {
    return map.keys[index];
  }

  function size(Map storage map) public view returns (uint256) {
    return map.keys.length;
  }

  function set(Map storage map, string memory key, uint256 val) public {
    if (map.inserted[key]) {
      map.values[key] = val;
    } else {
      map.inserted[key] = true;
      map.values[key] = val;
      map.indexOf[key] = map.keys.length;
      map.keys.push(key);
    }
  }

  function remove(Map storage map, string memory key) public {
    if (!map.inserted[key]) {
      return;
    }

    delete map.inserted[key];
    delete map.values[key];

    uint256 index = map.indexOf[key];
    string memory lastKey = map.keys[map.keys.length - 1];

    map.indexOf[lastKey] = index;
    delete map.indexOf[key];

    map.keys[index] = lastKey;
    map.keys.pop();
  }
}


and when I try to read that mapping back from a file with:
(string memory hitRateFilePath, bytes memory data) = _testFileLogging.updateLogFile(_map.getKeys(), _map.getValues());
        // IterableMapping.Map something = abi.decode(data, (IterableMapping));
    // IterableMapping.Map memory something = abi.decode(data, (IterableMapping));
    // IterableMapping.Map storage something = abi.decode(data, (IterableMapping));
    // IterableMapping.Map calldata something = abi.decode(data, (IterableMapping));

    // IterableMapping  something = abi.decode(data, (IterableMapping));
    // IterableMapping memory something = abi.decode(data, (IterableMapping));
    // IterableMapping storage something = abi.decode(data, (IterableMapping));
    // IterableMapping calldata something = abi.decode(data, (IterableMapping));

I get the error:
Compiler run failed:
Error (9574): Type library IterableMapping is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct IterableMapping.Map storage pointer.
   --> test/functional/DecentralisedInvestmentManager/triggerReturnAll/TestWithRandomNrOfInvestments.sol:108:5:
    |
108 |     IterableMapping.Map storage something = abi.decode(data, (IterableMapping));
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: 
Compilation failed
``

## Question
How can I decode the data that is written to file with:
```sol
function updateLogFile(
    string[] memory keys,
    uint256[] memory values) public returns (string memory hitRateFilePath, bytes memory data) {
    // initialiseHitRates();
    // Output hit rates to file if they do not exist yet.
    string memory serialisedTextString = convertHitRatesToString(keys,values);
    hitRateFilePath = createLogFileIfItDoesNotExist(_LOG_TIME_CREATOR, serialisedTextString);
    // Read the latest hitRates from file.
    data = readDataFromFile(hitRateFilePath);
    return (hitRateFilePath, data);
  }

back into the mapping?
